# Jquery Conditional Width of div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working in drupal. I have 2 floating div in 1 container div. The container width is 1000px which contains 2 floating divs col1 (width:700px) & col2(width:300px). In some pages I dont want col2 which is done through php condition in page.tpl.php

I need a way to rewrite the width of div id "col1" to 100% if there is no  available in the document or container div.

Comment: What do you mean by "if there is no available in the document"?

Comment: "if there is no col2 available in the document"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that?

```
if (!$("#col2").length) {
   $("#col1").css("width", "1000px");
}
```

Comment: little correction "if there is no col2 available in the document"

Comment: I am sorry, your answer is 100% correct but it wasn,t working for me due to JQuery conflict issue. it's working perfectly now. Thanks a  lot